# Incrementing variable in action creator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I was recently watching Dan Abramov redux series and one episode got me really curios. In this episode - [Redux: Extracting Action Creators](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-extracting-action-creators), timecode: 00:32~1:32 he's making action creator as a separate function (like it would normally look in the typical redux application) because:

> ... However, what if another component wants to dispatch the add todo
>   action? It would need to have the access to next **todo ID** somehow

But is that actually making any sense? In that particular example, `nextTodoId` variable (which is always incrementing) is available to all components inside that [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/?html,js,output) even if we don't extract action creator into a function.

Even if we'll imagine that it will be in a separate file (action creator), on each `import` that variable will be equal to the initial value (0) which breaks it's uniqueness concept.

So, what does he meant by that? How is that approach (of making action creators as a separate functions) will guarantee us the acccess to that **next** todo id variable?

Comment: That is a great question. It really doesn't make sense in JSBin since all the JS is in one place anyway. Usually with redux, you have a file just for "action creators". You'd put the `nextTodoId` variable in that file, then other files could import the `addTodo` function. No matter where you call `addTodo`, it will use and increment the same `nextTodoId`. (I believe that would be a closure).

Comment: It won't be reset to 0. It's a global variable, or if it's in its own module file, it's a module-level global, which means that every import shares the one variable value.

Answer (score 0):

You're focusing on the wrong aspect.  It's a fair enough point that this is a terrible way to store "current ID", but that isn't the purpose of the refactor he is showing.

The real purpose is that Components should be as agnostic about their context as possible.  A Component trying to "addTodo" really shouldn't be concerned with "what is the current max todo ID?".

In contrast, the actionCreator *is* concerned with this aspect.  It takes in data from the components and is then responsible for translating it to a dispatchable call that has real value.